# What does the sshd process from "ps aux" mean? Can I reconnect to it?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I started using Elastic Cloud Computing on AWS and noticed that when I close and reopen my laptop my ssh session is stuck. When I re-ssh into the virtual machine, it opens up a new session.

I ssh into the server using ec2-user username.

I wonder why the old ssh session is still running and can I reconnect to it?

> ps aux

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      2904  0.0  0.8 152692  8660 ?        Ss   20:28   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  2922  0.0  0.4 152692  4508 ?        S    20:28   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/2
root      3217  0.0  0.7 112916  7804 ?        Ss   06:35   0:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
root      3393  0.0  0.8 152692  8604 ?        Ss   22:26   0:00 sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user  3411  0.0  0.4 152692  4544 ?        S    22:26   0:00 sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ec2-user  3439  0.0  0.0 119424   932 pts/0    S+   22:26   0:00 grep --color=auto sshd
```

> ps auxwwf

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root     10472  0.0  0.8 152692  8516 ?        Ss   01:11   0:00  \_ sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user 10490  0.0  0.4 152692  4548 ?        S    01:11   0:00  |   \_ sshd: ec2-user@pts/0
ec2-user 10491  0.0  0.5 149940  5232 pts/0    Ss+  01:11   0:00  |       \_ zsh
root     10671  0.0  0.8 152692  8396 ?        Ss   01:17   0:00  \_ sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user 10689  0.0  0.4 152692  4352 ?        S    01:17   0:00  |   \_ sshd: ec2-user@pts/1
ec2-user 10690  0.0  0.3 124864  3936 pts/1    Ss+  01:17   0:00  |       \_ -bash
root     10774  0.0  0.8 152692  8560 ?        Ss   01:20   0:00  \_ sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user 10792  0.0  0.3 152692  3532 ?        S    01:20   0:00  |   \_ sshd: ec2-user@pts/2
ec2-user 10793  0.0  0.3 124864  3768 pts/2    Ss+  01:20   0:00  |       \_ -bash
root     14264  0.0  0.8 152692  8720 ?        Ss   02:13   0:00  \_ sshd: ec2-user [priv]
ec2-user 14282  0.0  0.4 152692  4540 ?        S    02:13   0:00      \_ sshd: ec2-user@pts/3
ec2-user 14283  0.0  0.5 152464  5688 pts/3    Ss   02:13   0:00          \_ -zsh
ec2-user 14311  0.0  0.4 164524  4036 pts/3    R+   02:19   0:00              \_ ps auxwwf
root      3254  0.0  0.0   4264   108 ?        Ss    2021   0:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
ec2-user  5688  0.0  1.8 370484 18460 ?        S     2021   0:11 python3 -m http.server
```

Comment: Can you post the output of "ps auxwwf"?

Comment: @A.Darwin I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not practical to recover a ssh session after a disconnect.

Consider using a terminal "detach" utility, like tmux or GNU screen. On reconnect these make it easy to reattach to a session. They also have window manager features.

Comment: When a session is disconnected why are there still running sshd processes?